# Space bar key press validation for text box with tinyMCE editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, tinymce

I have a ascx file in which i am using text box with tinyMCE editor. code is following..

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txbDiag" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100px"/>
<acr3s:tinymceextender runat="server" ID="TinyMceExtender4" TargetControlID="txbDiag" Theme="Full"/>
```

like this i have using 5 text box with tinyMCE extender

I am trying to validate my textbox with spacebar, If someone open my page and in text box click on spacebar and click on btn save it should not accept the value and give the error field should not be empty. the code which i use to validate is

```
if (txbDiag.Text.Trim().Length <= 0)
{
   msgError.Text =  "<b><font Color=red>*" + "fields are mandatory"+"</font>";
   msgError.Focus();
   return false;
}
```

and on btn click i use

```
txbDiag.Text.Trim();
```

but while clicking on btn save page is getting saved.

i used the js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function validate(e) {
    var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;

    if (unicode == 32) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

but this is also not working

I used regular expression and requir field validation that also not causing validation

HOW COULD I VALIDATE MY TEXT BOX FROM SPACEBAR HELP ME????

Comment: Spacebar is keyboard spacebar key

Comment: ah..ok. Why don't you use the functions the tinymce API provides? and btw. the tinymce editor is not inside a textarea - it is inside an own contenteditable iframe

Comment: can you please say me which function should i use for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Textbox1.Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "").Replace("<br />", "").Trim().Length <= 0)
{
    //Statement here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first you need to know that tinymce is NOT inside a textbox. Tinymce will create a contenteditable iframe and write back the content to a specified html element (textareas, divs, ps, aso...) from time to time on special events. So grabbing the txbDiag.Text is not very reliable. I suggest you use the tinymce API functions to get the content in order to verify it.

**1.** to get the right editor use

```
var my_editor = tinymce.get('txbDiag');
```

**2.** get the content

```
var my_content = my_editor.getContent();
```

**3.** Verification of the content: I am not sure what you want to verify exactly! (eighter that a space has been selected, that the content is empty or something else - please describe this EXACTLY)

In case you want to verify if the input is empty you can use

```
if ($(my_editor.getBody()).text() == '') alert('The input may not be empty!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you trim it on the user's side?
I would do the JS like:

```
if (yourTextBoxInnerPart.trim() == "")
{
    //textBox is empty or filled with spaces..
}
```

Comment: No its not validating i used it

Comment: If you have a textbox and in it, you got only spaces then there is no way that `.trim()` would not work. although, enter the spaces and then look with f.ex. F12 in IE what is the value of the checkbox. perhaps TineMCE changes spaces into &nbsp; ? either way look at the value of the textbox.